# Returned object modification java

Tags: java, reference

Some question on java basics,
the below function returns an object of Node type

```
class DS{
    public Node getNode(int index){
        return nodeList.get(index);
    }
}

public void test1(){
  DS ds = new DS();
  Node node = ds.getNode(3);
  // will the change in node variable(of test1()) change the actual Node object in ds?
  // Is there a simple way to create a copy to prevent source node's data modification?
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getNode()` method on the DS class returns a *reference* to the node stored in `nodeList`.  As such, if your `Node` class can be mutated (via setter methods or direct access to its fields), then yes, your code in `test1` will change the underlying (and now shared) Node reference.

If you want to "disconnect" the returned node from the node in your datastore, then you can [clone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29) it first.  Your node class will need to implement [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) and override the [`clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) method.  If you have only primitives in Node, then you can simply do:

```
public Object clone()
{
  return super.clone();
}
```

If you have other objects in Node, then the default clone operation will only make a *shallow copy*, and you will need to make your clone method more extensive so that it makes *deep copies*.  From the Javadoc for Object.clone():

> By convention, the object returned by this method should be independent of this object (which is being cloned). To achieve this independence, it may be necessary to modify one or more fields of the object returned by super.clone before returning it. Typically, this means copying any mutable objects that comprise the internal "deep structure" of the object being cloned and replacing the references to these objects with references to the copies. If a class contains only primitive fields or references to immutable objects, then it is usually the case that no fields in the object returned by super.clone need to be modified.

The change to your DS class will be:

```
public Node getNode(int index){
    return (Node) nodeList.get(index).clone();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, modifying the `node` in `test1()` will modify the object that's in `ds`'s list.  That's because it's a reference to the same object.

If you want to modify `node` without affecting the original, you need to make a copy — for example, do `new Node()` and then copy all the fields from the old one to the new one.  You could also implement the `Cloneable` interface and use the `clone()` method provided by the `Object` class.  Or give `Node` a constructor that takes another `Node` as an argument and copies its data.

Comment: FYI, The name given to a constructor that accepts another object of the same type and creates a copy from it is (unsurprisingly) a "copy constructor"

Comment: Doesn't the existing default clone method not suffice?
should I explicitly implement that?

Comment: @mrb - if you call `clone()` on an object that does not implement `Cloneable`, you get a `CloneNotSupportedException`.  Reference: javadocs for `Cloneable`.

Comment: If you implement `Cloneable`, you may also want to override `clone()` in your `Node` class.  Implement it as `Node cloned = (Node) super.clone(); /* other stuff */ return cloned;`  Since `Object.clone()` just does a field-by-field copy, the "other stuff" in your version should make copies of any object references held in fields (e.g. by calling `clone()` on them).  Also, your implementation of `clone()` can return `Node` rather than `Object`, so the caller doesn't have to cast the result.

Comment: @Wyzard 
Is is possible to do this automatically using Reflection API?
I don't know much about it, but we can get the variable names etc, from Reflection API, so can we get values too?

Comment: You can call methods (including getter methods) with reflection, so yes, you *could* do it that way, but I don't see why you'd want to.  There's no need for it; it'd just be unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will simply get a *reference* to the (same) Node object. Any changes made to it are reflected everywhere (threading issues notwithstanding).

To return a *copy* of the Node instead, do this:

Create a "copy constructor":

```
public Node(Node node) {
    // Copy all the fields across
    this.field1 = node.field1;
    this.field2 = node.field2;
    // etc
}
```

From your method, return a copy using the copy constructor:

```
public Node getNode(int index){
    return new Node(nodeList.get(index));
}
```

This code pattern is called "safe publishing" - your API safely provides objects to the caller and your class is safe from accidental modification of its state (ie fields).

Comment: What can I do to make a different object to be returned?

Comment: I would *not* use `Clonable`. I would simply make a copy constructor - see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

As others have mention, the answer is Yes.

An option not yet mentioned is to make the Node object [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Comment: Its not that I don't want to make changes,
I want to make changes, but I need a copy of that not original.
so, if we do not use a new keyword (some where in the code), its just a reference to the object. is this correct?